# Using integer variable in where clause of ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, sql, where-clause

I'm trying to include an integer variable in the SQL where-clause of a tool like this (ArcGIS 10 Python script):

```
newR = ExtractByAttributes(inR, '"IntField">=2508')
```

where inR is an integer raster, IntField is an integer field in its attribute table.

The above works, but how can I substitute an integer variable instead of 2508?

I've tried all kinds of different quotes and concatenation, but have not been able to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
val = 2508
newR = ExtractByAttributes(inR, '"IntField">=%d' % val)
```

[Read up on string formatting with python](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/lang/pytut/str-format.html).

Answer (score 4):

I have found ArcGIS to be very finnicky when it comes to multiple parameters. For example, use of double quotes tends to signify the end of a parameter. One method I use is string concatenation after changing the variable to a string.

`intstr = str(intvar) #Converts integer variable to a string

newR = ExtractByAttributes(inR, "IntField>= "+intstr)`